# iphone detailtext in UITableView question

Tags: iphone

So, I am able to create an array that populates the fields of the Table, but am having troubles creating the subtext that appears below the main fields.  I currently have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
listOfForms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listOfForms addObject:@"First Form"];
 }
```

and then:

```
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfDAForms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath portion.  Why can't I add:

```
listOfNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listOfNames addObject:@"Named Form"];
```

and

```
NSString *cellSubscript = [listOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellSubscript;
```

in order to make the little subview work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there, the problem must be somewhere else.  What is the actual symptom or error message?

Comment: there is no error, the subscript just doesn't display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to init your cell with the style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`